# UISheetPresentationController and UndimmedDetentIdentifier with custom Detent

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, uikit

How can I use LargestUndimmedDetentIdentifier with custom SheetPresentation height ?

I have a UISheetPresentationController with two customs Detents and I don't find how can interact with content underneath.

```
        UISheetPresentationController sheet = NavigationController!.SheetPresentationController!;
        sheet.PrefersGrabberVisible = true;
        sheet.PrefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false;
        sheet.WidthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true;
        sheet.Delegate = new SheetPresentationControllerDelegate();
        UISheetPresentationControllerDetent smallDetent = UISheetPresentationControllerDetent.Create("small", _ => 60);
        UISheetPresentationControllerDetent msmallPlusDetent = UISheetPresentationControllerDetent.Create("smallPlus", _ => 350);
        sheet.Detents = new UISheetPresentationControllerDetent[]
        {
            smallDetent,
            msmallPlusDetent
        };
        sheet.LargestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = ????; (what can I put here?)
```

Answer (score 0):

it asks detents identifier.. which is a property of "detent"
you can provide like `sheet.detents[0].identifier`

Answer (score -1):

Your custom detents height is an object that represents a height where a sheet naturally rests. The `LargeUndimmedDetentIdentifier` property needs to be an enumeration of `UISheetPresentationControllerDetentIdentifier`. Its function is that it doesn't dim the view underneath the sheet. At present, iOS only defines two enumeration types, Medium and Large, and there is no way to customize changes for the time being.
You can only use these two ways:`sheet.LargestUndimmedDetentIdentifier=UISheetPresentationControllerDetentIdentifier.Medium/Large`

For more details, you can refer to:

[largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier | AppleDeveloper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontroller/3858107-largestundimmeddetentidentifier?language=objc)

[UISheetPresentationControllerDetentIdentifier | AppleDeveloper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontrollerdetentidentifier?language=objc)